# Pig Latin involving digits

Tags: list, function, python-3.x

I'm new to computer programming and I'm trying to write a program that converts English into Pig Latin (For every word, move the first letter to the end of the word and add 'ay').

If the there is a number (in digits), multiply it by 2 and add 4.

```
ex. John has 4 cats --> ndaay ashay 12 atscay)
```

I got the first pig latin part down but can't seem to figure out the number part. My code accesses a text file but here is the program that would perform the string pig-latin. Where would I fit the number function?

```
    def pig_english():
        letterlist = [i + i[0] for i in read_script()]
        ayList = [i + 'ay' for i in letterlist]
        delaylist = [i[1:] for i in ayList]
        print (delaylist)
```

Comment: How does `John` become `ndaay`? Typo?

Comment: @logic, It's clearly not a typo. I think your dictionary is wrong. Haha. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can test if `i.isdigit()` and then cast to an int but it will be easier doing it all in one comprehension:

```
def pig_english(words):
    ayList = [str(int(i)*2+4) if i.isdigit() else i[1:]+i[0]+"ay" for i in words]
    print (ayList)
```

If you split the operations across multiple comprehensions then you will need to guard against ints:

```
def pig_english(words):
    numberlist = [int(i)*2+4 if i.isdigit() else i for i in words]
    letterlist = [i if isinstance(i, int) else i + i[0] for i in numberlist]
    ayList = [i if isinstance(i, int) else i + 'ay' for i in letterlist]
    delaylist = [str(i) if isinstance(i, int) else i[1:] for i in ayList]
    print (delaylist)

>>> pig_english("John has 4 cats".split())
['ohnJay', 'ashay', '12', 'atscay']
```